# Как пользоваться указателем вместо printf?

Tags: c

Я хочу использовать указатель на функцию вместо имени самой функции printf,поэтому делаю вот так:

```
 typedef struct DMA
{

     struct Console{
        //int(*printf)(const char *, ...);
         int _cdecl *k=&printf; //тут ошибка "требуется точка с запятой и подчёркивается знак равенства"

    } console;
};
```

Как можно создать указатель на функцию printf и пользоваться этим указателем как с printf?

```
typedef int(*func)(const char*, ...);
typedef struct DMA
{

     struct 
     {

          func f = printf; // по-прежнему ошибка "требуется точка с запятой и подчёркивается знак равенства"

     } console;
};
```

Comment: Инициализаторы полей в определениях классов - фича языка С++. Причем "новая", т.е. существующая только начиная с C++11. К языку С она никакого отношения не имеет. Зачем вы пытаетесь писать это `=` на поля структуры?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Примерно так:

```
typedef int (*func)(const char*, ... );

int main()
{
    func f = printf;
    f("Hello, %s\n","world");
}
```

**Update**

```
typedef int(*func)(const char*, ...);

typedef struct
{
     struct
     {
          func f;
     } console;
} DMA;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    DMA d;
    d.console.f = printf;
    d.console.f("Hello, %s\n","world");
}
```

Comment: ,а если int будет использоваться по ходу программы, коллизии с этим typedef не произойдёт?

Comment: Какой `int`? не очень понимаю, о чем вы. В typedef определен тип указателя на функцию от `const char*` и `...` :), возвращающую `int`.

Comment: можете посмотреть обновленный вопрос?

Comment: А в C вы не имеете права указывать в объявлении типа значение по умолчанию. Это вам не C++...